# Debian 8 files created with no group permissions

Tags: debian, permissions

I have setup Debian 8 and have it running well.

I have network access set up using samba.

When I create a folder over the network it has the permissions drwxr-sr-x. When I copy a file into a folder it is created with the permissions -rwxr-----.

Is there a way have these automatically set to -rwxrwxr-x when they are created?

Answer (score 0):

In the smb.conf file under [homes] I had

```
create mode = 0750
```

I then updated it to this

```
directory mask = 0775
create mode = 0775
```

Now when I create directories they are created as drwxrwxr-x and files are created as -rwxrw-r-- which works as I required.